# Permissions problems with Flutter and FireBase FireStore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am a complete beginner to FireStore and FireBase. I am trying to do something simple and FireBase is saying I do not have permission to do it.  I am using Flutter.  I have the following rules set up in FireBase rules console.  I only have one project and one Firestore database.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I have a collection of users setup which has a uid as the collection parameter and running the following code after signing into Flutter anonymously which does not throw an error.  UserID is set to a valid value.

```
void createUser(String userID, String userName, String password) async {

    final CollectionReference _users =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users");

    final data = {"Created": DateTime.now(), "LastLoggedIn": DateTime.now()};

    _users.doc(userID).set(data, SetOptions(merge: true));
  }
```

I am getting the following error message:

> 10.3.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Write at Users/QUIEvBpJeAgprgEan0S736aKjdk2 failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.

I am using anonymous log-ons.

Even when I use the following rules which is supposed to allow all reading and writing of the data I get the same error:

```
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I allowed several minutes to go by between setting the permissions and testing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the default rule with timestamp :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 11, 25);
    }
  }
}
```